Outdoor Plant Markers That Last
I'm on a mission to find a system for marking vegetables in our garden that will last through a Northwestern US summer. Plastic stakes & black Sharpie don't do the trick -- by this time (mid-summer) the "permanent" Sharpie has faded and is pretty much unreadable.
Ideally the markers would be relatively easy to clean and reuse as we often adjust the type and quantity of vegetables that we grow each year -- so I don't think the embossed copper ones would work (because I imagine that they would be hard to change).
I've seen some folks suggest a "wax pencil" on galvanized metal markers, but I'm not sure if any wax pencil would work or if there is something particular to look for.
What works for you?

Not really an answer, but an alternative method: use permanent marking, e.g. with numbers, and a blackboard in a shelter (or a note taking app). Plus side: you can take much more text/notes, and you bring with you in garden when needed.

You may also find answers on this question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4278/how-do-i-make-plant-labels-for-outdoors

Here's another question with ideas: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-can-i-use-to-quickly-and-inexpensively-create-metal-plant-labels

"China markers", aka Grease Pencils work great on galvanized markers. You "erase" them with a product like Goo Gone (petroleum-based) or possibly turpentine/mineral spirits; you can also use fine sandpaper (for metal) although that also often removes some or most of the galvanization.
One other suggestion is using a pencil on galvanized markers, especially a pencil with a soft lead. This will last a growing season but may not make it through the winter, which may be perfect for what you want.

Also another alternative; draw a map of your garden(s) to refer to during the growing season using colours and outlines.
Not really an answer sorry I don't have enough rep to comment
:)

A map is a marker to me :-).  Welcome to the site.
